# xrdp: Super_L not working

Tags: keyboard-layout

My virtual machine runs `xrdp` and when I connect with `rdesktop`, the "windows" key (i.e. Super_L) is not assigned properly.

Using `xev` I see that when the windows key is pressed, instead of showing <kbd>Super_L</kbd>, it shows `Control_L`. The real <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key also shows `Control_L`.

In other words, both the windows key and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> have the same effect.

How can I fix this, so that the Windows key maps to <kbd>Super_L</kbd>, same as on my laptop?